# Display dropdown values based on textbox value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one textbox and one dropdown. The textbox value, I am displaying whatever I am getting from response.

For example,

Dropdown values are,

$scope.newPlan = ["A","I","B","II","C","III"];

And my Textbox value is "A". The condition is, if my textbox value is "A", I need to show only "I" in a dropdown and remaining I don't want to show. Same as,

"A" -> "I"

"B" -> "II"

"C" -> "III"

I am using angularjs. How can I display this in a dropdown.

[image]

```js
It is ahowing all the values.

$scope.newPlan = ["A", "I", "B", "II", "C", "III"];
$scope.textboxValue = "A";
if ($scope.existingPlan == "A") {
  $scope.gpasPlan = $scope.newPlan[1];
} else if ($scope.existingPlan == "B") {
  $scope.gpasPlan = $scope.newPlan[3];
} else if ($scope.existingPlan == "C") {
  $scope.gpasPlan = $scope.newPlan[5];
}
```

```html
<select required name="selectnewPlan" ng-model="gpasPlan" ng-options="item for item in newPlan">
   <option value="">--Choose New Plan--</option>
</select>
```

How can I do this..

Comment: Why do u want to use dropdown If you just need to show one value for one input ( From text Box)?

Comment: Right now only one value, But in if future two or more will come. I need to select one value in a dropdown and I will submit it. So I need dropdown.

Comment: You should use a correct data structure then. It should be object of objects. Where at every object key is the character might be entered from text box and the value is an array of values that you want to show in drop down. For this structure ,it will be quite easy for you to achieve the goal

Answer (score 0):

May this help you :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <input type="text" ng-change="changeDropdownValue(existingPlan)"
            ng-model="existingPlan"> <select ng-model="selectedName"
            ng-options="x for x in newPlan">
        </select>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );
        app.controller( 'myCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
            $scope.changeDropdownValue = function ( data ) {
                $scope.newPlan = [
                        "A", "I", "B", "II", "C", "III"
                ];
                if ( $scope.existingPlan == "A" ) {
                    $scope.selectedName = $scope.newPlan[ 1 ];
                    $scope.newPlan = $scope.newPlan[ 1 ];
                    console.log( $scope.newPlan );
                } else if ( $scope.existingPlan == "B" ) {
                    $scope.selectedName = $scope.newPlan[ 3 ];
                    $scope.newPlan = $scope.newPlan[ 3 ];
                } else if ( $scope.existingPlan == "C" ) {
                    $scope.selectedName = $scope.newPlan[ 5 ];
                    $scope.newPlan = $scope.newPlan[ 5 ];
                }
            }

        } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i use ng-change in a textbox, is it will work? In dropdown it will work right? Sorry Surojit Jana, it is not working. Dropdown is showing all values.

Comment: No Surojit Jana, It is not even enter inside the changeDropdownValue function. Its not working.

Comment: If newPlan array and it's the corresponding array is going to increase every time then this logic won't work. Can you provide detailed requirement? it's better if you provide different array lists or nested object